# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, hash

Estoy haciendo un sistema de auth con python. En este momento estoy teniendo un problema al querer comparar la contraseña codificada que tengo en la bbdd con la que el usuario esta ingresando al querer iniciar sesión; les dejo cómo es que estoy guardando la contraseña en la bbdd a la hora de registrar y cómo es que las comparo en el inicio de sesión:

```
if len(cursor.fetchall()) > 0:
        conn.close()
        return {"error": True, "message": "El email ingresado ya se encuentra en uso."}
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    cursor.execute(insert_user, (nombre, apellido, usuario, email, sexo, born, hashed))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

simplemente lo que hago acá es mediante un if verificar si existe un email igual para poder responder que el email ya se encuentra en uso, luego utilizo `bcrypt` para cifrar la contraseña, esto se guarda perfecto a cuando mira la tabla que se creó:

```
conn = conectar()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    find_user = '''SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=%s'''
    cursor.execute(find_user, (usuario,))
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(row) == 1: 
        if bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), row[0][7]):
            #logica para mandarle datos de sesion al usuario
            pass
        else:
            return {"error": True, "message": "Contraseña incorrecta."}
            pass

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
    return {"error": True, "message": "error"}
```

en esta parte del código tengo dos condicionales, uno dentro de otro: el primero evalúa si hay un usuario con el nombre de usuario ingresado, si lo hay (>0) entonces verifico la contraseña, pero aquí es donde aparece el error que esta en el título:

> `Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.encode("utf8")
```

Obtiene la representación en `byte`s de los caracteres del `string` de acuerdo al encoding `UTF-8`.

```
b'$2b$12$.pOFnmb/qNWyROwLVf4glOYXyhQaw5joYjDmBygdAtkM4mgKTuT4a'
```

La `b` al inicio de la cadena indica que lo que estás viendo, no es un string, sino son `bytes` cuya representación como caracteres (en base 64 y el formato de bcrypt) es la que estás viendo. [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) pregunta tiene más detalles.

En criptografía casi todo se trabaja en operaciones bitwise, de ahí que sea necesario trabajar NO con strings, sino con bytes. Y eso es exactamente lo que te está diciendo el error, aunque no muy explícitamente.

> Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Quiere decir que debes primero obtener los bytes del string, pero recuerda que existen varios encodings y que los mismos bytes en un encoding pueden representar diferentes cosas en otro. Comunmente se trabaja con UTF-8 y por eso la necesidad de pasar el argumento `"utf8"`, pero podrías poner cualquier otro (aunque tal vez los bytes obtenidos no sean los mismos, intenta con `"utf16"`)

En fin, para solucionar el error hay que pasarle como argumentos a la función dos arreglos de `byte`, uno que sea la contraseña, y el otro que sean los bytes de esa contraseña hasheados. Para ello propongo dos opciones:

**Opción 1**

```
row_pwd = b'$2b$12$.pOFnmb/qNWyROwLVf4glOYXyhQaw5joYjDmBygdAtkM4mgKTuT4a'
password = "hola mundo"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), row_pwd))
```

**Opción 2**

```
row_pwd = '$2b$12$.pOFnmb/qNWyROwLVf4glOYXyhQaw5joYjDmBygdAtkM4mgKTuT4a'
password = "hola mundo"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), row_pwd.encode("utf8")))
```

¿Cuál opción utilizar? Depende de cómo estés obteniendo los datos de la base de datos (de cómo se almacenen en la DB y cómo te los regresa el conector).

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar si una contraseña es correcta se usa `checkpw` en vez de `hashpw`

por lo tanto tu código debería funcionar con

```
    if len(row) == 1: 
        if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), row[0][7]):
            #logica para mandarle datos de sesion al usuario
            pass
        else:
            return {"error": True, "message": "Contraseña incorrecta."}
            pass
```

Comment: cambie el `hashpw` por el `checkpw` y sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: lo que pude observas es que cuando estoy guardando la conrasea codificada por consola me muestra esto `b'$2b$12$.pOFnmb/qNWyROwLVf4glOYXyhQaw5joYjDmBygdAtkM4mgKTuT4a'` se puede notar que hay una `b` al principio y luego entre comillas un string, tendra algo que ver esto ?